# Jquery Select field populates Input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, input

I am trying to Select one of the options from the drop-down and populate the input field with the correct values.

I want to set the value 1 to ($100) val 2 to ($200)

I will not have access to a database to store the values.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="costfield" name=
            "costfield">
                <option value="Select Country"> Select Country</option>
                <option value="1"> country 1</option>
                <option value="2"> country 2</option>
                <option value="1"> country 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="estimate" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEstimate1" placeholder="Estimate">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $( "#costfield" ).val();
        $( "#estimate" ).text( "this" ).show();
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: if I am understanding the question correctly, it should be `$('#estimate').val($( "#costfield" ).val());`

Comment: I agree with @Sushil and I will be better if you target the correct element : `$('#exampleInputEstimate1').val($( "#costfield" ).val());`

Comment: Your input cannot have a `type` attribute holding the value "estimate", this is not valid.

Comment: did a quick edit to hide personal info. That is why some of the html is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('[name="costfield"]').change(function () {
    console.log("test");
    var cost = this.value;
    var str = "";

    switch (cost) {
        case "1":
            str = "$100";
            break;
        case "2":
            str = "$200";
            break;
    }
    $("#exampleInputEstimate1").val(str);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paew20kz/)

Comment: `$('#exampleInputEstimate1')`

Comment: @Michel Thanks. Misread that. The original HTML is not valid.

Comment: I dont believe the logic for this works. I have tested this out and it doesnt change the cost value

Answer (score 2):

You can store the values in the HTML5 `data-` attribute for each `<option>` element. This approach is useful when there is no direct relationship between the option's `value` attribute and the dollar value you are assigning it to.

p/s: `type="estimate"` is not a valid attribute value. Try `type="text"` (anyway, browsers will parse invalid type into `text` automagically.

```js
// Listen to change
$('#costfield').change(function() {
  $('#exampleInputEstimate1').val($(this).find('option:selected').data('dollar-value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="costfield" name="costfield">
      <option value="Select Country">Select Country</option>
      <option value="1" data-dollar-value="$100">country 1</option>
      <option value="2" data-dollar-value="$200">country 2</option>
      <option value="1" data-dollar-value="$100">country 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEstimate1" placeholder="Estimate" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to get the value from the Select when it changes and then change the value of the input accordingly. So put this in between the script tags.

```
$('#costfield').on('change', function() {
var value = $(this).val();
$('#exampleInputEstimate1').val(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either set your option values to be 100 or 200 then on any change in the drop down set the value of your input to the value.

```
$("#costfield").on("change", function(){
    $("#exampleInputEstimate1").val($("#costfield").val());
} );
```

If you want to keep your option values as they are then you can still use the same as above with a small change. (on the assumption that 1 will be 100, 2 will be 200, 3 will be 300, and so on)

```
$("#costfield").on("change", function(){
    $("#exampleInputEstimate1").val($("#costfield").val() + "00" );
} );
```

Also you may want to put a new option and set it as blank with no value that way you force the user to select something. Or you can set the input on document load and keep the number of options you have. AKA:

```
<option value="" ></option>
```